# Build app that uses CoreImage and disable it's features on iOS4

Tags: ios, ios4, ios5

I have an app that works well on iOS4. I want to add new features from iOS5 (CoreImage) and disable them for iOS4 users. I don't want to drop support for iOS4.

While I can test for functionality, once I add the CoreImage framework the app won't even build on iOS4. It crashes with:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/2EC8DC28-B109-48AD-8DEA-CC2DF1977C9C/App.app/App
  Reason: image not found
```

Is there a way to get the app running on iOS4 when CoreImage is added?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set `CoreImage` to link weakly. From the "Link Binary with Libraries" build phase, toggle the "Required" to "Optional" next to `CoreImage.framework`.

Oh and obviously code your app so that on iOS 4 it doesn't use any APIs from CoreImage or more generally, any APIs which were introduced in iOS 5.